# how to search array with showing one message

Tags: c#, arrays

How can I search for my Id in an array, if it finds my id, save it in `userseq`. if it does not find, return only a message (`Messagebox.Show("Does not exist"))` for all the cells of array(i mean after finishing the search `shows only one message`).

```
for (int yu = 0; yu <= 92161; yu++)
 {
   int wer = d[yu];
   if (wer == sc)
     {
       userseq = yu;
     }
 }
```

P.S: i tried before by

```
int? userseq=null;
...........
(!userseq.HasValue)
{
Messagebox.Show("Does not exist")
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? Do you get any errors? Does it not return the expected output (and if not, then what does it return and what are the expected results)? Looks like maybe you just forgot to add `if` at the start of the `if(!userseq.HasValue)` line?

Comment: When I insert wrong number to the system, it still show something as result that is not correct.Also I forget to add if here but in my code I used it. Also I cant use int? userseq=null; because userseq is "int" but "null" is boolean @BateTech

Comment: They don't work and completely messed up my script @GrantWinney.

Comment: Do you really have 92162 items in array d?  If so, then how are you verifying that the "wrong number" you insert for testing isn't in the array already in one of the other 92161 locations? There are several answers that have been posted across your 3 duplicate questions that do answer the question correctly, based on the information you have given.

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ:

```
int? foundId = arr.FirstOrDefault(a => a == userseq);
if (!foundId.HasValue) 
{
    Messagebox.Show("Does not exist!");
}
```

Where "arr" is the array and "userseq" is the ID you're comparing.

Just be sure to include System.Linq. You may need to cast the array to a list first. If so, just add ".ToList()" before ".FirstOrDefault"

More examples: http://www.dotnetperls.com/firstordefault

EDIT: Above assumes it's an array of Int?s. Otheriwse, FirstOrDefault will return 0 if it's an array of Ints.

```
int foundId;
if (!arr.Any(a => a == userseq) 
{
    Messagebox.Show("Does not exist!");
}
else
   foundId = arr.FirstOrDefault(a => a == userseq);
```

More "Any" examples: http://www.dotnetperls.com/any

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following

```
    int yu = 0;
    while (yu <= 92161)
    {
        if (d[yu] == sc)
        {
            userseq = yu;
            break;
        }
        yu++;
    }
    if (yu > 92161)
       MessageBox.Show("Does not exist")
```

In this way, if it finds the id, it will exit and will not print the message.
If after searching the whole array, it does not find, it will print the message.

Hope it helps.